# $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is not an Euclidian Domain

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

I want to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is not an Euclidian Domain.

First, I know that Euclidian  Domain $\implies$ principal, i.e., every ideal is principal. So, I want to construct a ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ that is not generated by a unique element $a+b\sqrt{-7}\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$, $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37468/show-that-the-ideal-2-1-sqrt-7-in-mathbbz-sqrt-7-is-no?noredirect=1&lq=1) the ideal $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-7})$ is not principal, but the answers uses some Galois Theory, and I haven't learned it yet.

My questions are:

- Where did the construction of this ideal come from? What is the motivation?
- How to prove that $I$ is not principal?

Comment: Use that Euclidean domain so UFD.

Comment: Note that norms don't require any knowledge of Galois theory, so the arguments in your linked post should be accessible to you.  The whole idea is to move certain questions of divisibility in your ring to divisibility of integers (the norms)

Comment: @BrianMoehring can you explain the first answer for me, please?

Comment: Hi. I feel [this earlier MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082113/mathbbz-bigl1-sqrt-7-bigr-is-not-euclidean) will be useful.

Comment: There is no Galois theory used in any of the linked answers (only a joke in a comment about user named Galois).  If you have questions about a particular answer then you should post them in comments on the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question becomes easier if we make it about inclusions of ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$, i.e. about divisibility of integers. To do this, all you need to know is that the *norm* function
$$\mathcal{N}:\ \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}:\ a+b\sqrt{-7}\ \longmapsto\ (a+b\sqrt{-7})(a-b\sqrt{-7})$$
is multiplicative. That is to say, for $x,y\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ you have $\mathcal{N}(xy)=\mathcal{N}(x)\mathcal{N}(y)$.

Now suppose the ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-7})\subset\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is principal, say it is generated by $x\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$. Then
$$2=xy\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 1+\sqrt{-7}=xz,$$
for some $y,z\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$. It follows that
$$\mathcal{N}(x)\mathcal{N}(y)=\mathcal{N}(xy)=\mathcal{N}(2)=4,$$
which shows that $\mathcal{N}(x)$ divides $4$. This leaves only a few cases to check:

1. If $\mathcal{N}(x)=\pm1$ then $x$ is a unit and so 
   $$(2,1+\sqrt{-7})=(x)=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}].$$
   Show that $(2,1+\sqrt{-7})$ is a proper ideal to arrive at a contradiction.
2. If $\mathcal{N}(x)=\pm2$ then writing $x=a+b\sqrt{-7}$ we find that
   $$\pm2=\mathcal{N}(x)=\mathcal{N}(a+b\sqrt{-7})=a^2+7b^2.$$
   Reducing mod $8$ yields a contradiction.
3. If $\mathcal{N}(x)=\pm4$ then $\mathcal{N}(y)=\pm1$ and so $y$ is a unit, so
   $$(2,1+\sqrt{-7})=(x)=(2),$$
   but it is clear that $1+\sqrt{-7}\notin(2)$, a contradiction.

This shows that the ideal is *not* principal.

Comment: I only have one question about 2.

"Reducing mod 8 yields a contradiction".
Could you explain me?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ isn't a UFD so in particular it couldn't be a Euclidean domain.
So let's study the element $8$. $$(1+\sqrt{-7})×(1-\sqrt{-7})=8=2×2×2.$$We have to show $2,1+\sqrt{-7},1-\sqrt{-7}$ are irreducibles.

Let study $1+\sqrt{-7}=(a+\sqrt{-7}b)(c+\sqrt{-7}d)$  $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$. Taking seminorms $(a^2+7b^2)(c^2+7d^2)=8\implies bd=0$ and both $b,d$ are not zero as $8$ has no integral square root. So without loss of generality assume $b=0$ and $d\not=0\implies 8=a^2(c^2+7d^2)$ . Note that $d$ must be $+1,-1$ , otherwise $c^2+7d^2\geq 28$. Also $c\not=0$ , as $7\not |8$. Hence $c$ must be $+1,-1$ otherwise $c^2+7d^2\geq 11$. Therefore $a=1,-1$ i.e. $a+\sqrt{-7}b$ is unit.

Now let $2=(a+b\sqrt{-7})(c+d\sqrt{-7})$ such that $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, then pass at the semi-norms :$$(a^2+7b^2)(c^2+7d^2)=4\implies b=d=0$$  $e,f\in \mathbb{Z}$ and wlog (because in $\mathbb{Z}$, $2$ is irreducible)  $$f\not =0\implies e^2+7f^2\geq 7$$ Also either $a$ or $c$ is $+1,-1$ as $2^2=4=(ac)^2$ and $\Bbb Z$ is a UFD i.e. either $a+b\sqrt{-7}$ or $c+d\sqrt{-7}$ unit.

In the same way $1-\sqrt{-7}$ is irreducible.